# Boost.Test linker error by use with precompiled headers (PCH)

Tags: c++, boost-test

I have a linker error when using Boost.Test with precompiled header (PCH) that does not occur without PCH. I use the dynamically linked library as described in [Usage variants](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/usage_variants.html).
How can I fix the error to use Boost.Test also with PCH?

The problem occurs at least with Fedora and boost 1.73 (has only dynamic libraries) and g++ 10/clang 11.

```
    $ cmake ../ && make
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: /home/.../boost_test_pch/build
    [ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/boost_utf_pch.dir/test_driver.cpp.o
    [ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/boost_utf_pch.dir/test.cpp.o
    [100%] Linking CXX executable boost_utf_pch
    [100%] Built target boost_utf_pch
```

vs.

```
    $ cmake -DEDA_ENABLE_PCH=TRUE ../ && make
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: /home/.../boost_test_pch/build
    [ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/boost_utf_pch.dir/cmake_pch.hxx.gch
    [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/boost_utf_pch.dir/test_driver.cpp.o
    cc1plus: warning: /home/.../boost_test_pch/build/CMakeFiles/boost_utf_pch.dir/cmake_pch.hxx.gch: not used because `BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK' is defined [-Winvalid-pch]
    [ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/boost_utf_pch.dir/test.cpp.o
    [100%] Linking CXX executable boost_utf_pch
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: in function `_start':
    (.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/boost_utf_pch.dir/build.make:138: boost_utf_pch] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:95: CMakeFiles/boost_utf_pch.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [Makefile:103: all] Error 2
```

I can not do anything with the warning message before ...

Here the playground files:

- CMakeLists.txt:

  ```
    project(boost_utf_pch LANGUAGES CXX)
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "")

    find_package(Boost 1.73.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS 
        unit_test_framework)

    target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        test_driver.cpp test.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        Boost::unit_test_framework)

    set_source_files_properties(test_driver.cpp
        APPEND PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK")

    option(EDA_ENABLE_PCH "Enable PCH" OFF)
    if (EDA_ENABLE_PCH)
        target_precompile_headers(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE pch.hpp)
    endif()
  ```
- pch.hpp

  ```
    #pragma once
    #include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
  ```
- test.cpp

  ```
    #include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( my_test )

    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( test_case1 )
    {
      BOOST_TEST_WARN( sizeof(int) < 4U );
    }

    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
  ```
- test_driver.cpp

  ```
    #define BOOST_TEST_MODULE "Boost.UTF PCH Test Suite"
    #include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
  ```

Comment: Note, using "Header-only usage variant" isn't really an option, since I've a lot of those test cases/testsuites.

Comment: I don't think you can, simply remove boost test from your precompiled header. All headers in the precompiled header have to have the same `#define`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alan Birtles got the hint into the right direction. I was not aware of the influence of the compiler switch BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK for the single file in the context of PCH here. A definition for all files of the project in the style of:

```
    target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        "BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK")
```

incomprehensibly does not solve the problem. Only after setting the property [SKIP_PRECOMPILE_HEADERS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/SKIP_PRECOMPILE_HEADERS.html) for driver 'main' it compiles and links as expected:

```
    project(boost_utf_pch LANGUAGES CXX)
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "")

    find_package(Boost 1.73.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS 
        unit_test_framework)

    target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        test_driver.cpp test.cpp)

    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        Boost::unit_test_framework)

    set_source_files_properties(test_driver.cpp
        APPEND PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK")
    set_source_files_properties(test_driver.cpp
        PROPERTIES SKIP_PRECOMPILE_HEADERS ON)
        
    option(EDA_ENABLE_PCH "Enable PCH" ON)

    if (EDA_ENABLE_PCH)
        target_precompile_headers(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE pch.hpp)
    endif()
```